# Is there a way to accomplish cascading copies of Entities in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

Suppose I have a table "Client" and a table "Contact". If I wanted to copy a Client row into my database along with new entries for Contacts (I don't want pointers to the already existing table) how could I accomplish this in a recursive way? I'd hate to have to go down to every table that "touches" these tables and manually create new rows with the same data, but new ID's. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you elaborate?  why copy at all when you can simply reference?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a partial class for you entity that implements ICloneable. Then, in your Clone() method, you can contain the logic for cloning that entity and its related entities.